Movie/ Short series about man telling his story to a servant
This could be a movie split into 3 parts, or a short show of 3 episodes.
Throughout the time, we hear an old man telling the story of his romantic endeavors (how he met his first love, how they broke up, how he found another girl and fall in love with her.. Maybe how he met the first love again... etc).
The spoken language is English. But the era could be medieval Spain, or England.
You could almost sense that they are remaking 1001 Arabian Nights if it wasn't for the single plot line. 
Typically, the girl serving/caring for the old man keeps asking him questions about how he reacted. Why he did what he did, etc. Ensuring the plot to move forward.
In one scene, they man meets a lovely person that he falls in love with. But discovers that the person is a man with feminine features. It is later revealed that the person is a woman, and she faked her gender to determine how much will that guy sacrifice to keep loving her (even if she were a man).
It might be a BBC production, I am not sure.

This is a common device (Amadeus immediately comes to mind as an example). Perhaps look through the examples on TV Tropes to see if you find it there.

I believe this is the 2005 BBC TV series Casanova starring Peter O'Toole as the older Casanova and David Tenant as the younger Casanova. 
One storyline has Casanova meeting, and falling in love with a castrato who turns out to be a woman in disguise. Here's a picture of them together:


That's it. You are a guenius

@Ahmad - It helps that I saw it too, and it was unique enough that it stuck in my head :D
